# Why sortBy() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, underscore.js

I've been trying to sort my dates in chronological order but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
 _.sortBy(data,function(a){
  return a.results;
});
```

Yet the output I'm getting is still wrong. The last few entries are not in the right place. The data being read is like this.

> {"count": 56, "results": [{"date": "2014-06-05T18:02:51", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014156LGN01"}, {"date": "2014-06-21T18:02:55", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014172LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-07-07T18:03:03", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014188LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-07-23T18:03:05", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014204LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-08-08T18:03:14", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014220LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-08-24T18:03:17", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014236LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-09-09T18:03:21", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014252LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-09-25T18:03:18", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014268LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-10-11T18:03:25", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014284LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-10-27T18:03:23", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014300LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-11-12T18:03:26", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014316LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-11-28T18:03:24", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014332LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-12-14T18:03:18", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014348LGN00"}, {"date": "2014-12-30T18:03:14", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014364LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-01-15T18:03:14", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015015LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-01-31T18:03:10", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015031LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-02-16T18:03:01", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015047LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-03-04T18:02:56", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015063LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-03-20T18:02:46", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015079LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-04-05T18:02:35", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015095LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-04-21T18:02:34", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015111LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-05-07T18:02:18", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015127LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-05-23T18:02:16", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015143LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-06-08T18:02:26", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015159LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-06-24T18:02:32", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015175LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-07-10T18:02:43", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015191LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-07-26T18:02:49", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015207LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-08-11T18:02:53", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015223LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-08-27T18:03:00", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015239LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-09-12T18:03:07", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015255LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-09-28T18:03:13", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015271LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-10-14T18:03:13", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015287LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-10-30T18:03:19", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015303LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-11-15T18:03:19", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015319LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-12-01T18:03:21", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015335LGN00"}, {"date": "2015-12-17T18:03:21", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015351LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-01-02T18:03:18", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016002LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-01-18T18:03:18", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016018LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-02-03T18:03:15", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016034LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-02-19T18:03:06", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016050LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-03-06T18:03:05", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016066LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-03-22T18:02:58", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016082LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-04-07T18:02:50", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016098LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-04-23T18:02:43", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016114LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-05-09T18:02:46", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016130LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-05-25T18:02:50", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016146LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-06-10T18:02:54", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016162LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-06-26T18:03:01", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016178LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-07-12T18:03:09", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016194LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-07-28T18:03:13", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016210LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-08-13T18:03:15", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016226LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-08-29T18:03:23", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016242LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-09-14T18:03:26", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016258LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-09-30T18:03:27", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016274LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-04-30T18:08:59", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80380352016121LGN00"}, {"date": "2016-05-16T18:08:57", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80380352016137LGN00"}]}

Answer (score 5):

You need to sort `results`, not the object itself. The sort function or parameter has to be wrapped into an array for using [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#sortBy).

```
sortedArray = _.sortBy(data.results, [function (a){
    return a.date;
}]);
```

or

```
sortedArray = _.sortBy(data.results, ['date']);
```

```js
var data = { count: 56, results: [{ date: "2014-06-05T18:02:51", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014156LGN01" }, { date: "2014-06-21T18:02:55", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014172LGN00" }, { date: "2014-07-07T18:03:03", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014188LGN00" }, { date: "2014-07-23T18:03:05", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014204LGN00" }, { date: "2014-08-08T18:03:14", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014220LGN00" }, { date: "2014-08-24T18:03:17", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014236LGN00" }, { date: "2014-09-09T18:03:21", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014252LGN00" }, { date: "2014-09-25T18:03:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014268LGN00" }, { date: "2014-10-11T18:03:25", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014284LGN00" }, { date: "2014-10-27T18:03:23", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014300LGN00" }, { date: "2014-11-12T18:03:26", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014316LGN00" }, { date: "2014-11-28T18:03:24", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014332LGN00" }, { date: "2014-12-14T18:03:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014348LGN00" }, { date: "2014-12-30T18:03:14", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014364LGN00" }, { date: "2015-01-15T18:03:14", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015015LGN00" }, { date: "2015-01-31T18:03:10", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015031LGN00" }, { date: "2015-02-16T18:03:01", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015047LGN00" }, { date: "2015-03-04T18:02:56", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015063LGN00" }, { date: "2015-03-20T18:02:46", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015079LGN00" }, { date: "2015-04-05T18:02:35", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015095LGN00" }, { date: "2015-04-21T18:02:34", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015111LGN00" }, { date: "2015-05-07T18:02:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015127LGN00" }, { date: "2015-05-23T18:02:16", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015143LGN00" }, { date: "2015-06-08T18:02:26", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015159LGN00" }, { date: "2015-06-24T18:02:32", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015175LGN00" }, { date: "2015-07-10T18:02:43", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015191LGN00" }, { date: "2015-07-26T18:02:49", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015207LGN00" }, { date: "2015-08-11T18:02:53", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015223LGN00" }, { date: "2015-08-27T18:03:00", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015239LGN00" }, { date: "2015-09-12T18:03:07", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015255LGN00" }, { date: "2015-09-28T18:03:13", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015271LGN00" }, { date: "2015-10-14T18:03:13", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015287LGN00" }, { date: "2015-10-30T18:03:19", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015303LGN00" }, { date: "2015-11-15T18:03:19", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015319LGN00" }, { date: "2015-12-01T18:03:21", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015335LGN00" }, { date: "2015-12-17T18:03:21", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015351LGN00" }, { date: "2016-01-02T18:03:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016002LGN00" }, { date: "2016-01-18T18:03:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016018LGN00" }, { date: "2016-02-03T18:03:15", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016034LGN00" }, { date: "2016-02-19T18:03:06", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016050LGN00" }, { date: "2016-03-06T18:03:05", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016066LGN00" }, { date: "2016-03-22T18:02:58", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016082LGN00" }, { date: "2016-04-07T18:02:50", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016098LGN00" }, { date: "2016-04-23T18:02:43", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016114LGN00" }, { date: "2016-05-09T18:02:46", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016130LGN00" }, { date: "2016-05-25T18:02:50", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016146LGN00" }, { date: "2016-06-10T18:02:54", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016162LGN00" }, { date: "2016-06-26T18:03:01", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016178LGN00" }, { date: "2016-07-12T18:03:09", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016194LGN00" }, { date: "2016-07-28T18:03:13", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016210LGN00" }, { date: "2016-08-13T18:03:15", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016226LGN00" }, { date: "2016-08-29T18:03:23", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016242LGN00" }, { date: "2016-09-14T18:03:26", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016258LGN00" }, { date: "2016-09-30T18:03:27", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016274LGN00" }, { date: "2016-04-30T18:08:59", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80380352016121LGN00" }, { date: "2016-05-16T18:08:57", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80380352016137LGN00" }] },
    sortedArray = _.sortBy(data.results, ['date']);

console.log(sortedArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Sorting with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), in situ.

```js
var data = { count: 56, results: [{ date: "2014-06-05T18:02:51", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014156LGN01" }, { date: "2014-06-21T18:02:55", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014172LGN00" }, { date: "2014-07-07T18:03:03", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014188LGN00" }, { date: "2014-07-23T18:03:05", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014204LGN00" }, { date: "2014-08-08T18:03:14", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014220LGN00" }, { date: "2014-08-24T18:03:17", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014236LGN00" }, { date: "2014-09-09T18:03:21", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014252LGN00" }, { date: "2014-09-25T18:03:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014268LGN00" }, { date: "2014-10-11T18:03:25", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014284LGN00" }, { date: "2014-10-27T18:03:23", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014300LGN00" }, { date: "2014-11-12T18:03:26", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014316LGN00" }, { date: "2014-11-28T18:03:24", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014332LGN00" }, { date: "2014-12-14T18:03:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014348LGN00" }, { date: "2014-12-30T18:03:14", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352014364LGN00" }, { date: "2015-01-15T18:03:14", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015015LGN00" }, { date: "2015-01-31T18:03:10", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015031LGN00" }, { date: "2015-02-16T18:03:01", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015047LGN00" }, { date: "2015-03-04T18:02:56", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015063LGN00" }, { date: "2015-03-20T18:02:46", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015079LGN00" }, { date: "2015-04-05T18:02:35", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015095LGN00" }, { date: "2015-04-21T18:02:34", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015111LGN00" }, { date: "2015-05-07T18:02:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015127LGN00" }, { date: "2015-05-23T18:02:16", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015143LGN00" }, { date: "2015-06-08T18:02:26", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015159LGN00" }, { date: "2015-06-24T18:02:32", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015175LGN00" }, { date: "2015-07-10T18:02:43", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015191LGN00" }, { date: "2015-07-26T18:02:49", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015207LGN00" }, { date: "2015-08-11T18:02:53", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015223LGN00" }, { date: "2015-08-27T18:03:00", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015239LGN00" }, { date: "2015-09-12T18:03:07", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015255LGN00" }, { date: "2015-09-28T18:03:13", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015271LGN00" }, { date: "2015-10-14T18:03:13", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015287LGN00" }, { date: "2015-10-30T18:03:19", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015303LGN00" }, { date: "2015-11-15T18:03:19", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015319LGN00" }, { date: "2015-12-01T18:03:21", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015335LGN00" }, { date: "2015-12-17T18:03:21", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352015351LGN00" }, { date: "2016-01-02T18:03:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016002LGN00" }, { date: "2016-01-18T18:03:18", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016018LGN00" }, { date: "2016-02-03T18:03:15", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016034LGN00" }, { date: "2016-02-19T18:03:06", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016050LGN00" }, { date: "2016-03-06T18:03:05", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016066LGN00" }, { date: "2016-03-22T18:02:58", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016082LGN00" }, { date: "2016-04-07T18:02:50", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016098LGN00" }, { date: "2016-04-23T18:02:43", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016114LGN00" }, { date: "2016-05-09T18:02:46", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016130LGN00" }, { date: "2016-05-25T18:02:50", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016146LGN00" }, { date: "2016-06-10T18:02:54", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016162LGN00" }, { date: "2016-06-26T18:03:01", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016178LGN00" }, { date: "2016-07-12T18:03:09", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016194LGN00" }, { date: "2016-07-28T18:03:13", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016210LGN00" }, { date: "2016-08-13T18:03:15", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016226LGN00" }, { date: "2016-08-29T18:03:23", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016242LGN00" }, { date: "2016-09-14T18:03:26", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016258LGN00" }, { date: "2016-09-30T18:03:27", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80370352016274LGN00" }, { date: "2016-04-30T18:08:59", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80380352016121LGN00" }, { date: "2016-05-16T18:08:57", id: "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80380352016137LGN00" }] };

data.results.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.date.localeCompare(b.date);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what is not working? the `_.sortBy` returns the sorted array. it does not sort in situ as `Array#sort` does.

Comment: I did this  var sortedArray =[];
    sortedArray = _.sortBy(data.results, [function (a){
    return a.date;
    }]);

Comment: but it gives me the same result as before

Comment: but in the above output, the results is sorted?

Answer (score 0):

```
var sampleData = {
    "count": 56,
    "results": [{
            "date": "2015-06-05T18:02:51",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-06-21T18:02:55",
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-07-07T18:03:03",
            "id": "3"
        },
        {
            "date": "2008-07-23T18:03:05",
            "id": "4"
        }
    ]
};
_.sortBy(sampleData.results, 'date');
```

There was one quote less in object line 3